# Помещение последнего элемента списка на первое место при уменьшении ширины окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, ul

Есть список в котором при определенной ширине окна нужно поледний элемент поставить на первое место. Делаю это так :

```js
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
  $('.header_bar').prepend($('.header_bar li:last'));
} else {
  $('.header_bar').append($('.header_bar li:last'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header_bar">
  <li><a href="#" class="text">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">TEAM</a></li>
</ul>
```

Но это срабатывает только если я выставлю ширину и обновлю страницу. Как сделать так что бы это работало сразу при изменении ширины окна?(если есть вариант без js буду рад услышать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.header_bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header_bar li {
  order: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .header_bar li:last-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="header_bar">
  <li><a href="#" class="text">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">TEAM</a></li>
</ul>
```

Тестируйте в полноэкранном режиме, нажав "развернуть фрагмент" или [в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/5fxbevzg/), изменяя размер фрейма вывода результата.

Answer (score 2):

Понятно, что это будет срабатывать на каждый `resize`. Попробуйте хранить последний размер и тасовать элементы, только если размер изменился, перейдя значение 500 в одну из сторон.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('.header_bar').prepend($('.header_bar li:last'));
  } else {
    $('.header_bar').append($('.header_bar li:last'));
  }
});
$(window).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header_bar">
  <li><a href="#" class="text">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="text">TEAM</a></li>
</ul>
```